# How to stack all permutations of few multidimension arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, stack

I was working with a few multidimensional arrays, facing these challenges.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.rand(63, 1, 4)
b = np.random.rand(63, 1, 4)
c = np.random.rand(63, 1, 4)
d = np.random.rand(63, 1, 4)

combined_array = [a, b, c, d]
```

Now I want all possible positional permutations of a, b, c, d like a-c-d-b, a-d-b-c,.... and I used this code,

```
permutated_list = list(itertools.permutations(combined_array))
```

Now I want to stack those arrays one upon another in all possible permutations and return to me each a separate array.

I tried to clarify what I exactly wanted with an example given below.

```
tt = np.hstack(permutated_list[0])
```

This code will return me back the stacked array of the first element of the permutated list. The length of the permutated list is 4!=24, so I want all those stacked 24 arrays separately; something like tt_0 will store the first one and so on,

tt_0 = np.hstack(permutated_list[0])

tt_1 = np.hstack(permutated_list[1])

.
.
.

tt_23 = np.hstack(permutated_list[23])

Like this way.
Please help me with this.

Comment: `np.concatenate(list(zip(*permutations(lst))), 2)`

Comment: Hi, thanks; I'm very new to this python programming. Could you please write one answer with proper logic, I found little hard to follow.